# What is the best practice for obtaining admin consent for GRAPH-API based Outlook Addin?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am currently creating an (MS GRAPH-based) Outlook addin, that is installed domain-wide. We only do side-loading when running some tests or for some custom builds. This addin is virtually complete feature wise, so it works as it was designed.

My inquiry however, is related to the best way of granting consent/permissions for the addin. Currently what I am doing is, ask our customer-admins to access https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx. This will then show a popup asking for the admin to grant consent on different permissions. Once he or she, accepts, they will then be redirected to a simple congratulations page.

That being said, is the method I am doing a 'standard practice' for granting consent? Is this the right way to do it, when we publish/release our product to the market?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way of granting permissions with admin consent,
[image]

Refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#3-get-administrator-consent) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. This is currently the way I am doing it.  Your answer is good enough for me.

Comment: Glad that the answer has helped you, Thanks for accepting.